# Make rectangle in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I stuck on the basics of Unity. I want to make a scene for mobiles in which there are four different coloured rectangles that take 25% of the screen each.

[image: Mobile scene]

I tried making an GameObject Image, "registering" it as a prefab in Inspector.
Below code is an example of how I tried to make a single red rectangle and position it on the (x,y,z) => (0,0,0) coordinates on my scene.
Several problems are present:

- Rectangle did not appear
- I don't know how to programatically specify width and height of the rectangle

This is how it looks:

```
public class SceneScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject prefab;

    void Start () {
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        GameObject gameObject = Instantiate(prefab);
        Image image = gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
        image.color = new Color(1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);

        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Is there an easier solution, or is this the best practice + could you please provide me some hints what should I do?

Comment: In your scene hierarchy, can you confirm that you are successfully instantiating the object? If so, when you review the properties of the object, how do they differ from what you expect?

Comment: You can't have an `Image` render without a `Canvas` as a parent somewhere in the `GameObject` heirarchy.

Comment: @Serlite I right clicked on Hierarchy panel->UI->Image, which makes Canvas and Image object as his child. Then, I made that object as a prefab, then connected it using interface with the Gameobject itself. But, had no luck displaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have a `Canvas` in your heirarchy.  Here's how you can programmatically create your `Canvas`, your `Image` and their containing `GameObject`s:

```
    using UnityEngine.UI; // Defines Image class that is a component. using UnityEngine.UIElements instead will throw error.

    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    GameObject parentGameObject = new GameObject();
    Canvas canvas = parentGameObject.AddComponent<Canvas>();

    GameObject imageGameObject = new GameObject();
    imageGameObject.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform);

    Image image = imageGameObject.AddComponent<Image>();
    image.color = new Color(1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);

    imageGameObject.transform.position = pos;
```

This will create a full-screen, red rectangle.  Play around with the `RectTransform` settings in the inspector after these are created and you should be able to figure out how to size them properly.

Comment: Thank you, this is a functional and complete solution to my problem. Other than that, is this the best practice, to make it all from script?

Comment: @spamserv Those decisions come down to how portable you'd like this to be as well as how important performance is.  `AddComponent` is a fairly slow function; if you're doing it a lot, it's noticeable and using prefabs could help avoid that (you'd just call `GetComponent` after instantiating the prefab if you still need a reference to a particular component).  On the flip-side, doing everything via scripts helps with portability because the features are self-contained; they don't require extra assets to function.

Comment: In terms of best practice: it depends. If you always have the same four squares but you only want to make them appear on some event: then create them in the editor by hand and only set their state from isEnabled=false to isEnabled=true.

Comment: The same goes for when you have four squares but you just want to change their color then create the squares by hand and reference them (their Image component) in a script, where you set the color prior to setting their enabled flag to true. I'd say to create them only programmatically when you need a variable amount of them.